# Reemplazar un caracter repetido mas de 2 veces php

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente string:

$var = "123, 444, , , , 555";

lo que deseo es obtener "123, 444, 555"

yo e intentado con esto pero no me funciona:

```
function clearImei($str)
{
    $res = preg_replace('/(,){0,2}+/', '', $str);
    return $res;
}
echo clearImei($var);
```

Pero me retorna esto:
123444555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres es eliminar las comas seguidas y que queden comas individuales entre 2 valores. Tu expresión regular no funciona porque estás diciendo esto:
reemplaza con vacío `''` todo lo que sea `,` en 0 o más repeticiones, así que eliminará todas las comas.

En el caso hay otro problema, no son simples comas seguidas, si no, coma con espacio, entonces el regex sería:

```
> $var = "123, 444, , , , 555";
> echo preg_replace('/[,\s]+/', ',', $var);
123,444,555
```

Si la cadena no tiene espacios entonces basta con `[,]` y si no supieras qué puede traer la cadena, entonces `[,][,\s]` es el caso general que serviría para ambos.

```
> $var = "123, 444,, ,, 555"; // Un espacio en medio de las comas
> echo preg_replace('/[,][,\s]+/', ',', $var);
123,444,555
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, me sirvio